# Removing empty bbcode tags using regex

Tags: regex, bbcode

Using regex I'm trying to remove empty bbcode tags.  By empty I mean nothing in between them:

```
[tag][/tag]
```

If there is something between them then it should be kept.

I've searched a lot and played around with a regex tester but haven't come up with anything that works right.

Edit: I realize now why I was having a hard time with this.  In addition to the example above, I also have one's like:

```
[url=http://www.somedomain.com/][/url]
```

I'm trying to cleanup bbcode when a form is submitted so it's not stored since it's unneeded.

Comment: Which language are you using? Javascript? PHP?

Comment: I'm doing this in .NET.  I'm not sure which it's compatible with.

Comment: updated to include a subset of the second case.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you could do :

```
str.replace(/\[([^\[\]]*)\]\[\/\1\]/g, '');
```

Comment: Might wanna make the `.*` lazy (`.*?`), otherwise you might consume more than expected.

Comment: True. Also, I will change it so it will only match characters which are not brackets, even more safe.

Answer (score 0):

The operative aspect of regex in this case is the use of internal backrefs; I'm not sure, off the top of my head, whether this is universally supported, but .NET, in any case, seems to use PCRE (is this true?).

The pattern, then, is `[`, a word, `][/`, the same word, `]`. If we assume the word has simply the quality of "does not contain `]`", then an appropriate regex to match an empty tag is `\[([^\]]+)\]\[/\1\]`, escaped as necessary in context.

For the second case, if assume the form `[tag=arg][/tag]`, and that tag and arg each don't contain any `']'` (not a reasonable assumption! but dealing with it is left as an exercise for the reader -- and I'm quite sure most bbcode implementations don't actually deal with that problem, either), one could use a regex `\[([^\]=]+)(=[^\]]*)?\]\[/\1\]`.

Comment: it's worth keeping in mind that my assumptions on what constitutes a valid tag may or may not be valid; the examples given are provided more to show the principle than to be used directly, although they certainly can be.